# Set and use PowerShell variable in CMD

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I'd like to send an Email from within my (existing) `.bat` using `Send-MailMessage`. Since it should be automated I stored the secured password to `MailPW.txt` already. 
In the script I'd like to use it, but unfortunately the `$cred` variable is empty (I assume the `$pw` as well).

```
...Rest of .bat Script (ROBOCOPY Commands)...

powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command " & {$pw = Get-Content .\MailPW.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString}"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command " & {$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "zyx@othermail.com", $pw} "
powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Command Send-MailMessage ^
    -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" ^
    -UseSsl ^
    -To "xyz@mail.com" ^
    -From "zyx@othermail.com" ^
    -Subject "Testing" ^
    -Body "Hello" ^
    -Port "587" ^
    -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) ^
    -Credential $cred
```

I also tried

`-Credential "& {New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "zyx@othermail.com", Get-Content .\MailPW.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString}"`

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486552/1092632) without any success.

Basically I want to set a `$cred` var and use it in the next command, is that even possible with this approach?

Comment: is `.\MailPW.txt` relative to the script's path?

Comment: It is in the same directory

Comment: Variables aren't persistent. You should do all your commands within the same Powershell session. Why don't you write the whole script in Powershell?

Comment: As you're not actually running any `PowerShell` scripts, there's no need to use `-ExecutionPolicy ByPass` for any of those commands

Comment: I have a `bat` file which I run in my CMD. I'd like to add the above.
@montonero, how would I pipe the first two lines into the `Credentials` param as attempted in my last step?

Comment: PowerShell commands can be daisy-chained with semicolons. But frankly, since PowerShell can run external commands (like `robocopy`) just fine you'd be better off rewriting your batch script in PowerShell.

Comment: The easiest way to implement it with a mixed cmd/Powershell approach is to make a separate `.ps1` script and run it from within the batch script. Or, as @AnsgarWiechers has mentioned, write all commands in one long line although I find this way pretty clumsy and hard to read.

Comment: So you should replace `.\MailPW.txt` by `"%~dp0MailPW.txt"`...

Answer (score 0):

You are opening three different powershell sessions. (your problem)

Just merge all commands into a single .ps1 file

```
$pw = Get-Content .\MailPW.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "zyx@othermail.com", $pw
Send-MailMessage ^
    -SmtpServer "smtp.office365.com" ^
    -UseSsl ^
    -To "xyz@mail.com" ^
    -From "zyx@othermail.com" ^
    -Subject "Testing" ^
    -Body "Hello" ^
    -Port "587" ^
    -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) ^
    -Credential $cred
```

And call the powershell script inside your .bat file

`powershell -File Script.ps1`